# ubuntu 13.10 liveboot/installer loads dots, then does nothing

Tags: installation, 13.10, live-usb, setup

**Problem:**  When I load an Ubuntu 13.10 (64-bit) live USB / installer on my laptop, the purple Ubuntu screen with the white dots appears, the dots turn orange (indicating its loading), then after a few seconds the screen turns completely black and nothing else happens.  I can not install Ubuntu 13.10 on this computer.

**What I've Tried:**  I've re-downloaded the .iso file from canonical.  I've burned the .iso to the USB using the default linux usb image writer, and the Windows programs YUMI and Linux Live USB Creator; same thing happens each time.  Yes, I'm sure my computer is 64 bit.  I'm currently running Linux Mint 15 on it, which runs perfectly.  It's a Sager NP7330 / Clevo w230st.

**extra info**  A few months I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on this machine, which installed perfectly. Normally I'd install that then dist-upgrade to 13.10, HOWEVER this computer is only a few months old and the wireless/network drivers for my network card were not implemented until kernel 3.11 (which comes w ith 13.10).  I tried manually downloading kernel 3.11 and installing it (on 13.04), however the wireless card nor ethernet card still did work with Ubuntu 13.04.  So my only real hope is to get 13.10 working.

Does anyone know what's up with this?

Comment: Use alt+tab to know where it has got stuck. It will be stuck at loading some program etc. Reply here.

Comment: I used alt+tab a bunch of times, and the screen stays black.  Nothing changes, nothing comes up to show me anything.  I even tried Ctrl+tab, and Alt+Ctrl+F1 through F7 (then F8).

Comment: please respond.

Answer (score 0):

When booting (on the Grub menu) edit the boot command and remove the "splash" flag from the command. That will let you boot into the live distro and install everything. Once installed, everything will work just fine.

More info here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here, also with a Sager NP7330; solved it by using the -nomodeset boot option when booting up (I believe the kernel used in 13.10 cannot automatically detect/use the video hardware on this machine like it does with others).

For more information, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions.